# from class to functions React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change a class component to a function component but I am not sure how to proceed. I have tried to change the state for useState but then I fail on passing the information to the state itself, so then the URL for instance is always null, so it does not work. Can anyone give a hint on how to fix it?

```
class Recording extends Component {
  state = {
    audioDetails: {
      url: null,
      blob: null,
      chunks: null,
      duration: {
        h: 0,
        m: 0,
        s: 0,
      },
    },
  };

  handleAudioStop(data) {
    this.setState({ audioDetails: data });
  }

  handleRest() {
    const reset = {
      url: null,
      blob: null,
      chunks: null,
      duration: {
        h: 0,
        m: 0,
        s: 0,
      },
    };
    this.setState({ audioDetails: reset });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Recorder
          record={true}
          audioURL={this.state.audioDetails.url}
          showUIAudio
          handleAudioStop={(data) => this.handleAudioStop(data)}
          handleRest={() => this.handleRest()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Recording;
```

```
export default function Recording(props) {
  const [rec, setRec] = useState({
    audioDetails: {
      url: null,
      blob: null,
      chunks: null,
      duration: {
        h: 0,
        m: 0,
        s: 0,
      },
    },
  });

  const handleAudioStop = (data) => {
    setRec({ audioDetails: data });
    console.log(rec);
  };

  const handleRest = () => {
    const reset = {
      url: null,
      blob: null,
      chunks: null,
      duration: {
        h: 0,
        m: 0,
        s: 0,
      },
    };
    setRec({ audioDetails: reset });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Recorder
        record={true}
        audioURL={props.audioDetails.url}
        showUIAudio
        handleAudioStop={(data) => handleAudioStop(data)}
        handleRest={() => handleRest()}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are trying to access the url from props instead of state.  audioURL={props.audioDetails.url} should be audioURL={rec.audioDetails.url}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a **audioURL={props.audioDetails.url}** you can't write props here. Because props use in child component, when child get data from perent, child use props to fecth data. As I can see in your class component you used **this.state.audioDetails.url**. So what you have to do is correct your code **audioURL={rec.audioDetails.url}**.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs:](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates)

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

Another option is [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer), which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.